# Why are Delta 15 N and Delta 13 C not included in the simplified Palmer Penguin dataset?

Tags: dataset

I was looking at the Palmer Penguin dataset and noticed that it had two versions, one simplified and the other raw. While I understand why columns such as `Comments` were removed in the simplified version, I don't understand why two columns labeled `Delta 15 N (o/oo)` and `Delta 13 C (o/oo)` were not included in the simplified version.

I plan to test some clustering algorithms on the dataset and was wondering if including these two columns in my input would cause my tests to be inaccurate in some way.